# how to resolve of height issue in Responsive?

Tags: jquery, html, css, cordova, responsive-design

i have two phone like one has 320 width and 508 height, second one have 320 width and 610 height. oN this situation i am total black to set height by responsive.

Please help me out..

```
 <div class="wrapper mm-page">
      <div class="maindiv">
        <div class="fix">
          <div class="top">
          <div class="col12">
            <div class="col2">
              <div class="menu"> <a href="#menu"><img alt="" src="images/menu.png" class="btn-exit" id="trigger"></a> </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col8">
              <div class="personal"> אזור אישי </div>
            </div>
            <div onclick="goToFilterSearch();" class="col2">
              <div style="background-color:#fff!important;" class="search"> <a href="#"><img alt="" src="images/search.png"></a> </div>
            </div>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="col12">
          <div class="clear"></div>
          <div class="middle">
            <div class="col12">
              <div onclick="goToSearchList();" class="col6">
                <button class="job">
                  <img alt="" src="images/job.png">
            </button>
              </div>
              <div onclick="goToJobOpening();" class="col6">
                <button class="open">
                <img src="imgaes/img1.jpg">
                </button>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col12">
              <div class="col6">
                <button class="job3 nospace"> 
<img src="imgaes/img1.jpg">
                </button>
              </div>
              <div class="col6">
                <button class="job4 nospace"> 
<img src="imgaes/img1.jpg">
                </button>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
```

Thanks,
Salehin

Comment: Ok what element is suppose to have a responsive height? What do you have so far? Show us some relevant code.

Comment: I had tried media query of 320 width and also given height 100%, but even though its not friendly to both of this above mention height. Code description(Main Div has one center heading and below heading thier is 4 square button. and this is HTML code of phone Gap.)

Comment: Actually i had paste code here, but its not range of characters limit.

Comment: If i could I would give you -1. So what is suppose to have 100% height? where is your css?

Comment: Normally you would make the width responsive, not the height. For that purpose something called scroll is often used. Any reasons why you'd want to have a fixed height?

Comment: yes, because it was landing screen. we cant keep scroll here.

Answer (score 0):

Why not add window resize event and do calculation for your height there as require?
And as per your window height, update height of your other elements on page.

Comment: actually i am not that much awar about it... can you please give me some example of it... Thanks, Salehin

Comment: Can you place your code somewhere like jsfiddle or anything so we can test it?